# Removing the part of the string

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsrange

I wanted to get the substrings from the whole string.

```
NSString *temp = @"Hello World <script> XXX </script>Test";
```

I wanted to delete the strings from `<script>` to `</script>` 
The final string should be like this - `Hello World Test`.

I tried to do it with `NSRange` but unable to succeed.

Comment: The string already says "Hello World Test".

Comment: regular expressions to the rescue!

Comment: Show us what you tried. What worked and what went wrong? We'd be more than happy to help, but we want to see your effort before we put in ours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do such a thing for example:

```
NSString *_tempString = @"Hello World <script> random text </script>Test <script> much more random text </script>!";
NSError *_error;
NSRegularExpression *_regExp = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"<script>.*?</script>" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&_error];
NSArray *_matches = [_regExp matchesInString:_tempString options:NSMatchingReportCompletion range:NSMakeRange(0, _tempString.length)];
NSMutableString *_finalString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:_tempString];
for (int i = _matches.count - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    NSTextCheckingResult *_result = [_matches objectAtIndex:i];
    [_finalString deleteCharactersInRange:_result.range];
}
```

the console says:

```
Hello World Test !
```

---

*NOTE: the code is just a representative one – working well but you may need to add more error-handling to the code, if you'd like to insert it into a proper application.*